# class loading priority when same class in .java and .jar

Tags: java, class, loader

I am developing spring boot application.

It imports some custom jar. And I want to override this custom library.

So I copy source code from custom jar file, and then paste it in my spring boot application.
( I don't want to edit and deploy custom jar )

When I edit this source code that is copy/pasted, I can find jar is ignored and source code I edited is activated.

I want to confirm it is right and the reason.

ps. I know java class loader and its priority. rt.jar < ext jar < custom class.

Comment: You haven't given any detail, so in general extend and override the relevant methods, not copy/paste the class with some changes.

Comment: Class loaders load the first class they come across with the correct class name.  The class loader order in your project is source code, jar.